# Is there a way to have the C Preprocessor resolve macros in an #error statement?

Tags: c++, c-preprocessor

Just as the title says. I want to use a preprocessor macro in the text of an #error statement:

```
#define SOME_MACRO 1

#if SOME_MACRO != 0
    #error "SOME_MACRO was not 0; it was [value of SOME_MACRO]"
#endif
```

In this example I want the preprocessor to resolve `[value of SOME_MACRO]` to the actual value of `SOME_MACRO` which in this case is 1. This should happen before the preprocessor, compiler or whatever processes #error prints the error output
Is there a way to do that or is this just not possible?

I don't want to know if there is an ISO C++ standard way to do that, because afaik the preprocessor directive `#error` is not stated in any ISO C++ standard. However, I know GCC and Visual C++ support `#error`. But my question is not specific to those compilers, I'm just curious if any C/C++ compiler/preprocessor can do that.

I tried to search for that topic but without any luck.

Comment: If you're using C++0x static_assert can do almost exactly this, or you can use the one in boost which supports more compilers. I'm not aware of any other way of achieving this functionality though.

Comment: #error is actually part of standard C++, but I'm not aware of any way of doing what you want.

Comment: I didn't know about static_assert yet. It's useful but I still had a hard time to get the value of the macro into the error text.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For completeness the C++0x way I suggested (using the same trick as Kirill):

```
#define STRING2(x) #x
#define STRING(x) STRING2(x)

#define EXPECT(v,a) static_assert((v)==(a), "Expecting " #v "==" STRING(a) " [" #v ": "  STRING(v) "]")


#define VALUE 1

EXPECT(VALUE, 0);
```

Gives:

```
g++ -Wall -Wextra -std=c++0x test.cc                     
test.cc:9: error: static assertion failed: "Expecting VALUE==0 [VALUE: 1]"
```

Comment: Very nice, works flawlessly. Now I have to decide which method to use... Technically both answers awoodlands and Kirills solve the issue. For now I favor the static_assert a little over the #pragma message/#error one.
Thanks for your answers

Answer (score 6):

In Visual Studio you can use `pragma`[`message`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x7dkzch2.aspx) as follows:

```
#define STRING2(x) #x
#define STRING(x) STRING2(x)

#define SOME_MACRO 1

#if SOME_MACRO != 0
    #pragma message ( "SOME_MACRO was not 0; it was " STRING(SOME_MACRO) )
    #error SOME_MACRO was not 0;
#endif
```

This will generate two messages, but you'll get the value of `SOME_MACRO`. In G++ use the following instead (*from comments: g++ version 4.3.4 works well with parenthesis as in the code above*):

```
#pragma message "SOME_MACRO was not 0; it was " STRING(SOME_MACRO)
```

Comment: Interesting, and useful.  Thanks!  If you have the `#pragma` in there, you need the `#error` too, of course, and if the compiler doesn't recognize the pragma, it will ignore it - and it just degrades the diagnostic slightly, but you've done the best you can in the circumstances.  Also, the parenthesized version works in G++, so you can use the same mechanism in both MSVC and G++.  Interestingly, GCC 4.6.0 (as opposed to G++) seems to ignore `#pragma message`.

Comment: Thanks, this does the trick: The parenthized version works also for G++ version 4.3.4

Answer (score 4):

```
#define INVALID_MACRO_VALUE2(x) <invalid_macro_value_##x>
#define INVALID_MACRO_VALUE(x) INVALID_MACRO_VALUE2(x)

#if SOME_MACRO != 0
  #include INVALID_MACRO_VALUE(SOME_MACRO)
#endif
```

generates "Cannot open include file: 'invalid_macro_value_1': No such file or directory" in Visual Studio 2005 and probably similar messages on other compilers.

This doesn't answer your question directly about using #error, but the result is similar.

Comment: This also works for me in XCode 5. Nothing else did.