# Concatenate string in #error preprocessor symbol

Tags: c, c-preprocessor, string-concatenation

I'm trying to do some preprocessor magic. It all works great, except for the error-reporting:

```c
#define N 10
#if N != 9
    #error "N is supposed to be 9, got "N" instead"
    #error "N is supposed to be 9, got " ## N ## " instead"
#endif
```

Instead of getting the desired output `N is supposed to be 9, got 10 instead` in either or both cases as a compiler error, I am getting the less desirable

```
test.c:3:6: error: "N is supposed to be 9, got "N" instead"
    #error "N is supposed to be 9, got "N" instead"
     ^
test.c:4:6: error: "N is supposed to be 9, got " ## N ## " instead"
    #error "N is supposed to be 9, got " ## N ## " instead"
     ^
2 errors generated.
```

Is there any way to concatenate strings in `#error`-messages?

Comment: It's not possible to concatenate `" string "` with `N`. But why use a string? Just `#error N is supposed ...`. Also note, you are asking XY question. You are _not_ asking how to display the value of N in `#error` message. You are specifically asking about concatenating strings in `#error`. Did you research similar questions? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27635947/gcc-macro-expansion-of-error https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12637392/c-preprocessor-expand-macro-in-a-warning

Comment: @KamilCuk Is it possible to get a `#error` to report anything other than the literal characters until the next newline?

Comment: I believe there are some serious gymnastics you can do to achieve this, but it's ugly. This seems mostly on point: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6002594/is-there-a-way-to-have-the-c-preprocessor-resolve-macros-in-an-error-statement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do it with `#error` but it is possible with `#pragma message`

```
#define XSTR(x) #x
#define STR(x) XSTR(x)

#define N 10
#if N != 9
#pragma message "N= " STR(N)
#error See message above
#endif
```